Cloud liquid water content and rain precipitation high resolution dataset
I am searching for datasets in a high spatial resolution. I was using satellite data from the NASA website, but as I'm working in a particular small town in Japan, I need a higher-resolution dataset for that. I couldn't find satellite data with a spatial resolution of less than km2. Is there any website that could offer the dataset for cloud liquid water content and rain precipitation with a spatial resolution in m2 so it would be more detailed for me to use compared to the satellite images
